# Rebinding deserialized data to their static counterparts

Tags: vb.net, serialization

I have a static database of around ~30 items in the program, then I create a dynamic database(basically a hash table) consisting of thousands of objects that each refer to one of the items in the static database. Then I serialize the dynamic db into binary and save it on a file and then I load it and deserialize.

What I would like to happen is that when loaded, the dynamic objects would refer to the same static objects for the sake of memory conservation but what really happens is upon serialization, the static db objects get serialized and stored per each dynamic object and upon deserializing they create a lot of duplicates of the base objects that should be static.

To illustrate, I wrote this:

```
Public Class Form1
    <Serializable> Public Class Banana
    End Class

    <Serializable> Public Class Orange
        Public MyBanana As Banana
    End Class

    Public GreatBanana = New Banana

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim BF As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
        Dim MS As New IO.MemoryStream

        Dim FreshOrange = New Orange With {.MyBanana = GreatBanana}
        BF.Serialize(MS, FreshOrange)

        MS.Position = 0
        Dim RefridgeratedOrange As Orange = BF.Deserialize(MS)

        MsgBox(RefridgeratedOrange.MyBanana Is GreatBanana)

    End Sub


End Class
```

The "GreatBanana" variable plays the role of the static database with one item in it. We find out that the banana in RefridgeratedOrange is no longer the same as the one in FreshOrange (even though data wise they would be identical)

Is there a way to indicate to the serializer that this data member should be a static one?

Comment: Partly, in case you make it so that you could identify which GreatBanana (unique id or something), you could write a public property inside your Orange class instead of the field you have now and check your cache in the setter if there is already an object with the unique id, the public property would then translate the cache for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do it in a way that it would be invisible for your end user to worry about, however, it won't the fastest algorithm (partly because each time the `MyBanana` property is requested, it gets checked in the cache)

I wrote a small test case with your code to demonstrate what a possible solution might be. For the test itself, i also added a class that contains a unique id, and overrides the `Equals` & `GetHashCode` methods, it's not necessary on the Orange class, but would be necessary to all items you which to add to the cache.

The Property `MyBanana` inside the Orange class does the reading and setting of the cache itself, the console program does some basic tests to see if our assumptions were correct. But as i said, don't use this to increase your programs performance ;)

```
Module Module1
    Public NotInheritable Class CacheHolder
        Private Shared ReadOnly cacheSet As HashSet(Of IDHolder) = New HashSet(Of IDHolder)

        Public Shared Function GetFromCache(Of T As IDHolder)(obj As T) As T
            If obj Is Nothing Then
                Return obj
            End If
            Dim result As T
            result = (From item In cacheSet Where item.Equals(obj) Select item).FirstOrDefault()
            If result Is Nothing Then
                cacheSet.Add(obj)
                Return obj
            End If
            Return result
        End Function

        Public Shared Sub Add(Of T As IDHolder)(obj As T)
            GetFromCache(obj)
        End Sub

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property Count As Integer
            Get
                Return cacheSet.Count
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property Item(index As Integer) As IDHolder
            Get
                Return cacheSet(index)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Shared Function Contains(Of T As IDHolder)(item As T) As Boolean
            Return cacheSet.Contains(item)
        End Function
    End Class

    <Serializable>
    Public Class IDHolder
        Protected _id As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
        Public Property ID
            Get
                Return _id
            End Get
            Set(value)
                _id = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
            If Type.Equals(obj.GetType(), Me.GetType()) Then
                Return Guid.Equals(DirectCast(obj, IDHolder).ID, Me.ID)
            End If
            Return MyBase.Equals(obj)
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
            Return Me.ID.GetHashCode()
        End Function
    End Class

    <Serializable> Public Class Banana
        Inherits IDHolder

        Public Property Title As String
    End Class

    <Serializable> Public Class Orange
        Inherits IDHolder

        Private _myBanana As Banana
        Public Property MyBanana As Banana
            Get
                Return CacheHolder.GetFromCache(_myBanana)
            End Get
            Set(value As Banana)
                _myBanana = CacheHolder.GetFromCache(value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Title As String
    End Class

    Private Sub Serialize(Of T)(item As T, stream As IO.Stream)
        Dim binaryFormatter As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, item)
    End Sub

    Private Function Deserialize(Of T)(stream As IO.Stream) As T
        Dim binaryFormatter As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
        If stream.CanSeek Then
            stream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
        End If
        Return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream)
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim MAX_CACHE As Integer = 100
        Dim MAX_OBJECT As Integer = 10000

        Console.WriteLine("Creating {0} bananas", MAX_CACHE)
        For i As Integer = 1 To MAX_CACHE
            Dim staticBanana As New Banana With {.Title = "Banana #" & i.ToString().PadLeft(3, "0")}
            CacheHolder.Add(staticBanana)
        Next

        Dim rand As New Random()
        Dim lstOfOranges As New List(Of Orange)
        Console.WriteLine("Creating {0} Oranges", MAX_OBJECT)
        For i As Integer = 1 To MAX_OBJECT
            Dim index As Integer = rand.Next(CacheHolder.Count)
            Dim orange As New Orange With {.MyBanana = CacheHolder.Item(index), .Title = "Orange #" & i.ToString().PadLeft(3, "0") & " with " & .MyBanana.Title}
            lstOfOranges.Add(orange)
        Next

        Dim stream As New IO.MemoryStream

        Console.WriteLine("Serializing")
        Serialize(lstOfOranges, stream)
        Console.WriteLine("Deserializing")
        lstOfOranges = Deserialize(Of List(Of Orange))(stream)
        Debug.Assert(CacheHolder.Count = MAX_CACHE, "The cacheholder holds more object than originally put in, nl: " & CacheHolder.Count)
        Debug.Assert(lstOfOranges.Count = MAX_OBJECT, "The list of oranges isn't as big as it supposed to be, nl: " & lstOfOranges.Count)

        Console.WriteLine("Getting distinct banana's")
        Dim query = (From item In lstOfOranges Select item.MyBanana).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(i) i.Title).ToList()
        ' <= because it could be not all banana's were referenced with the randomizer
        Debug.Assert(query.Count <= CacheHolder.Count, "There were more banana's in the distinct list than in the CacheHolder, this cannot be!")

        Console.WriteLine("Checking if the distinct banana's were all found in the query")
        For Each item In query
            Debug.Assert(CacheHolder.Contains(item), item.ID.ToString() & " not found in CacheHolder!")
            Dim cacheItem As IDHolder = CacheHolder.GetFromCache(item)
            Debug.Assert(cacheItem Is item, "Item and cacheItem are not the same!")
            Dim totalOranges As Integer = (From orange In lstOfOranges Where orange.MyBanana.Equals(cacheItem)).Count()
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} oranges attached to {1}", totalOranges, CType(cacheItem, Banana).Title)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("Done")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```